# Project reload issue in Visual Studio 2022 after resolve conflicts in proj file

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2022

After the last update to Visual Studio 2022, I am facing issues while resolving conflicts in .proj file after merging. It is reloading the project automatically without loading its dependencies. Because of this, all its references are being removed from other project files. What should be the possible solution? Before it, I used to reload the project with all its dependencies manually.

Because of this, I need to manually change all other projects on which conflicted project reference were removed. I need to mannual reload that project with all its dependencies to resolve this issue. I tried to repair and back to previous version but no results.